# Convert String representation of a List to a Dictionary Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

How can I convert a str representation of the `list`, such as the below string into a `dictionary`?

```
a = '[100:0.345,123:0.34,145:0.86]'
```

Expected output :

```
{100:0.345,123:0.34,145:0.86}
```

First tried to convert the string into a list using `ast.literal_eval`. But it's showing an error as :  `invalid syntax`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's showing as invalid syntax because it has the wrong brackets, so you could do

```
ast.literal_eval(a.replace("[","{").replace("]", "}"))
```

Or alternatively parse the string yourself in a dictionary comprehension

```
{x.split(":")[0]: x.split(":")[1] for x in a[1:-1].split(",")}
```

and if as mentioned there are `[` or `]` elsewhere in your string the following may be more robust

```
ast.literal_eval("{" + a[1:-1] +"}")
```

Comment: This won't work if there are additional `[`s or `]`s inside quoted string literals, such as `'[100:"[",123:0.34,145:0.86]'`

Comment: @blhsing see edit for an approach which should be more robust in that case

Answer (score 5):

I would simply try

```
eval(a.replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}'))
```

Comment: [Why is using eval a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) - ast.literal_eval is safer.

Comment: It depends on where `a` comes from ... if it is not from user input, it might be a pain to import `ast` just for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

To convert to a dict:

#### Code:

```
data = '[100:0.345,123:0.34,145:0.86]'

new_data = dict(y.split(':') for y in (x.strip().strip('[').strip(']')
                                       for x in data.split(',')))

print(new_data)
```

Or if you need numbers not strings:

```
new_data = dict((map(float, y.split(':'))) for y in (
    x.strip().strip('[').strip(']') for x in data.split(',')))
```

#### Results:

```
{'100': '0.345', '123': '0.34', '145': '0.86'}

{145.0: 0.86, 123.0: 0.34, 100.0: 0.345}
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate brackets to braces, `literal_eval`.

```
rebracket = {91: 123, 93: 125}
a = '[100:0.345,123:0.34,145:0.86]'
literal_eval(a.translate(rebracket))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a string representation of a dict:

```
a = '[100:0.345,123:0.34,145:0.86]'
```

Ignore the containing braces `[..]`, and break up the elements on commas:

```
a = a[1:-1].split(",")
```

For each element, separate the key and value:

```
d1 = [x.split(":") for x in a]
```

Reconstitute the parsed data as a dict:

```
d2 = { int(k[0]) : float(k[1]) for k in d1}
```